# mysql_fetch_object() or mysql_fetch_array() which is better and why?

Tags: mysql

mysql_fetch_object() or mysql_fetch_array() which is better and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are good. Choose what you like more - objects or arrays.

It's even better to use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql extension.